# I want to install hardhat but after installing I want to run it by npx hardhat , its not running

Tags: hardhat, configuration

```
PS C:\Users\HP-PC\OneDrive\Desktop\NFT demo> npx hardhat
WARNING: You are using a version of Node.js that is not supported, and it may work incorrectly, or not work at all. See https://hardhat.org/nodejs-versions


An unexpected error occurred:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at extendEnvironment (C:\Users\HP-PC\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\config\config-env.ts:130:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP-PC\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\index.ts:19:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)     
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP-PC\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-chai-matchers\src\index.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: First of all, you should upgrade Nodejs to make sure the incompatibility you are warned about is not the root of the error.